# How to fix "No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.delete()" to delete a object?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm new in grails and I'm trying to delete all the objects (ArrayList) that I'm getting.

This is the method to get the data, that is working:

```
def authRequest = User.findAllByExpiresLessThan(currentDate)
```

And this is that I'm trying to do:

```
if(authRequest){
    authRequest.delete()
}
```

This is the error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.delete() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: sleep(long), sleep(long, groovy.lang.Closure), clear(), clear(), clear(), clone()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authRequest.delete()` would work if it was only 1 object.

When you use [`findAllBy`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) instead of [`findBy`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html), it will return an array of objects, instead of just one. In that case you can use ["Spread" operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_spread_operator) (`*.`) to delete them all:

```
authRequest*.delete()
```

Comment: While this will work, it's inefficient insofar as it will execute a separate `DELETE` statement for each object

Answer (score -1):

I would use HQL to delete all the objects atomically, with a single (SQL `DELETE`) statement

```
User.executeUpdate('delete User where expires < ?', [currentDate])
```

Comment: Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead